# Strange Usage of エフエー (FA)?

Tags: meaning, usage

I was watching an anime, and there was a scene in which the protagonists, after sneaking into a morgue, find their own dead bodies and confirm that they are, in fact, dead (there's lots of occult-y stuff going on, don't worry about it). Anyway, during the reveal, the main character says:

```
「まじで？僕ら死んじゃったでエフエーなの？」
```

I looked up what エフエー meant since it was clearly meant to be FA, which should be an abbreviation for something, but none of the words it stood for seemed to make sense for the context. I found things like Free Agent, Factory Automization, etc., but none of those make sense in this context. I guess the least weird one would be Free Agent, but unless there's some meaning to that phrase that Japanese has come up with separate from the English definition, it doesn't make sense. The translation that was given was, "Seriously? So we all died and that's it?" I don't have any problems with the grammar, it all flows normally, but I can't tell what FA is--we all died and what, exactly?

Comment: I have the impression that the use of 「…でFA[なの]?」 originates from 2ch but not sure.  Related article from 同人用語の基礎知識 : [FA/ ファイナルアンサー/ 同人用語の基礎知識](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_fa.htm)

Comment: This word shouldn't be known by everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The translation that was given was, "Seriously? So we all died and that's it?"

How about the エフエー is ***final answer***?

Comment: Not to scream, "I don't believe you!", but is there precedent for this abbreviation? None of the dictionaries I found listed it, but is it common slang anyway? Not to be a pain, but I'd like sources to back it up, although it does make some sense.

Comment: A kind of KY語 that DAIGO who is a Japanese singer-songwriter, actor, talent, and voice actor started. As for ファイナルアンサー, it has become a loanword now. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/KY%E8%AA%9E

Comment: I knew about final answer as a loanword and its meaning, to address Yuuichi Tam's answer below, but I hadn't ever seen it be abbreviated. But thinking about it, it does make sense, so I'm accepting this answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

ファイナルアンサー is a popular phrase which was said by a quizmaster in his popular TV game show. He said it when he confirmed with a panelist whether your answer was final. There are some meanings of an abbreviation FA and this エフエー(FA) would be an abbreviation of ファイナルアンサー(Final Answer) to judge the meaning by the context.

This is the TV show: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2MqV4VioMo

Comment: Thank you for the answer--I did know about the TV show, and the fact that ファイナルアンサー is a well-known phrase--in fact here in America we have the same show with the same line said.

Comment: @Kurausukun Sure, [the Japanese version is based on the original US version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_versions_of_Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire%3F) :)